# Current Transformer Current Sensing via operational-amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, current-transformer, current-sensing

[image]

This is a current sensing circuit, L1(CT2320) is a current transformer, U1 is generated by IGBT inverter ，U is one of a three phase  of the motor driver voltage. I have several questions about this circuit.

1. **What's role of the resistors R9 and R10 respectively?  Also why are they  connected in parallel and can they combined into one resistor?**
2. D1 is a Schottky barrier diodes，here how it works？ Is it necessary?can I remove it，why?
3. I know the function of R4 and E1 in parallel is to filter, but what's role of them respectively?
4. How should I analyze the entire circuit in this picture? How to analyze voltage and how the current flows？

Comment: R9 and R10 are there to convert the CT's output current to a voltage; without them the CT will destroy your circuit. I don't have the time right now to go into any detail, so I won't be writing a full answer.

Comment: I understand what you say, R9 and R10 is Current sensing resistor. But I don't know how to analyze R9 and R10 in circuit. For example, what is the magnitude of the voltage at each end of the R9 respectively and how current flows in R9 and R10, what's role of them respectively ?

Answer (score 1):

I answer each question in their order of appearance, so let's start:

> 1. **What's role of the resistors R9 and R10 respectively?  Also why are they  connected in parallel and can they combined into one resistor?**

As Hearth writes in [their comment above](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/669704/current-transformer-current-sensing-via-operational-amplifier#comment1783158_669704), R9 and R10 are the shunt resistor used by the current transformer in order to provide a correct and well defined \$I_\text{in}/V_\text{out}\$ ratio so that reading the voltage across their parallel combination \$R_9\parallel R_{10}\$ is equivalent to read the input current. Regarding their use, possibly it is only due to the fact that the resistance value of their parallel combination is perhaps closer to the theoretical value required than the nearest 1% value resistor (\$R_\text{shunt} \simeq 71.347\Omega\simeq 71.5\Omega\$).

> 2. D1 is a (couple of) Schottky barrier diodes，hear how it works？ Is it necessary? Can I remove it，why?

D1 rectifies the output of the differential amplifier made with \$U_\text{1A}\$ in order to provide an output that is close to the peak value of the input voltage (and thus follows quite faithfully the peak of the input current). Its presence could be mandatory or not, depending on the structure of the circuit which follows. This also implies that it could be necessary or not and you can remove it or not only depending on the needs of the following (not shown) circuit.

> 3. I know the function of R4 and E1 in parallel is to filter, but what's role of them respectively?

They are simply the components of the RC lowpass filter of the peak rectifier made with D1.

- E1 stores the peak output voltage from \$U_\text{1A}\$ and prevents the output voltage of the whole circuit to follow it immediately after the peak voltage has been stored.
- R4 discharges E1 in such a way that it can be used to store the very next peak value

> 4. How should I analyze the entire circuit in this picture? How to analyze voltage and how the current flows？

You should put a current generator between the pins 1 and 2 of the current transformer, then plot the voltage between the output pins 3 and 4, the voltage between pin 1 of \$U_\text{1A}\$ and ground and finally the voltage across R4.

Comment: We can assume that U is AC230V,  the voltage of the pin 8 and pin 4  respectively of operational-amplifier is   +12V and -12V.   1. then we how to design the the resistance value of current sensing resistor, which is the resistance value of R9 and R10 after parallel.               2. What's the magnitude of voltage in the pin 4 and pin 3 respectively of current transformer?  Is the voltage of the pin 3 of the current transformer zero?